# mysql duplicate key update issue

Tags: mysql

I have my index set to the field: testsuite_id and I'm executing the following query:

```
 INSERT INTO testsuite_dates (testsuite_id,start_date,end_date) 
 VALUES ('27798','2012:02:27 00:00:00','2012:02:28 00:00:00') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE testsuite_id='27798';
```

I would expect this to update the entry if an entry for testsuite_id exists or insert it if it doesn't but if I execute this query a second time it inserts a second entry with the same testsuite_id.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "on duplicate key update" only changes the fields YOU specify in the 'update' portion. You're updating only the key field, which triggered the constraint violation in the first place. The other fields are silently dropped, so you're effective doing `update yourtable set id=id where id=xxx`.

You have to list each field you want to be updated:

```
INSERT INTO testsuite_dates (testsuite_id,start_date,end_date) 
VALUES ('27798','2012:02:27 00:00:00','2012:02:28 00:00:00') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    start_date=values(start_date), end_date=values(end_date)
```

Note the use of the `values()` function in the update portion. This allows you to refer to the NEW value that would've been inserted, and use it for the update portion. This saves you having to embed the same data twice in the same query. Not a big deal for a few dates or numbers, but if you're inserting large blobs, it makes for a HUGE query string size savings.

Comment: I didn't realize I had to pass the same values twice (start_date and end_date).  I thought I was specifying the index ID to insert/update.  That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Then you don't have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key on `testsuite_id`.

Answer (score 0):

did you set your testsuite_id to be a primary key, or have unique constraint

Comment: testsuite_id is set to be UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO testsuite_dates (testsuite_id,start_date,end_date) 
 VALUES ('27798','2012:02:27 00:00:00','2012:02:28 00:00:00') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE testsuite_id=testsuite_id+1;
```